# Python Requests form automation - combine POST request responses (XMLHttpRequests) and text inputs for a single form

Tags: javascript, python, forms, python-requests, xmlhttprequest

## Question:

I’m trying to automate form filling for this site: https://secure.ami.co.nz/css/car/step1#noBack

*How* can I **combine**:

1. The responses from Form elements that require “onclick” POST requests (XMLHttpRequests)
   , and,
2. Other Form input fields data (text/radio inputs) that just need to be passed values ...

... In the same session, to fill this form completely, and then submit it?

## Background

Im working with the car insurance quote web-form to get quotes (Fields are car rego; address; name; email etc). Calling it example_site - which I am loading as so:

```
import requests
url = "https://example_site.com"
payload = {}
headers = {}
response_site = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
```

The form has text inputs such as name, but also some onclick events (XMLHttprequests) for address and rego (to determine vehicle make and address).

I have determined how to submit a POST request for these onclick events in isolation to generate a response, by using dev tools and the network tab, to generate the below code. Example below for rego = abc321:

```
url = "https://example_site.com/searchVehicleByRegNo"
payload = "regNo=abc321"
headers = {
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
     'Host': 'secure.ami.co.nz',
     'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}
# Post response contains all information on vehicle
response_rego = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
```

Note: avoiding Selenium as is overkill for this purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't Seem like you need to do those request in the same session, infact if you look at the final request that was made at `secure.ami.co.nz/url/css/car/step2/`:

```
vehicle.redbookVehicleKey=NZVDAEW2001AEAF
garagingAddress.manualSuburbTown=ARO VALLEY, WELLINGTON 6011
policy.coverageTypeCd=FULL
vehicle.isManualEntry=false
vehicle.searchRegNo=abc321
garagingAddress.fullAddress
garagingAddress.manualUnitNumber=a
garagingAddress.manualStreetNumber=a
garagingAddress.manualStreetName=a
garagingAddress.isManual=true
garaging.garagingCd=OTH
policy.effective=2020-09-18
vehicle.hasImmobilizer=false
vehicle.isBusinessUse=false
transferKey=xxxx
ccssSessionId=xxxx
...
```

You'll find the "Vehicle Key" was sent as the response for the `searchVehicleByRegNo`

```
{
  "registrationNo_vehicleList": [
    {
      "id": null,
      "vehicleCode": "NZVDAEW2001AEAF",
      "registrationNo": "ABC321",
...
```

Which you can use in the payload of your final request.

Though Mind you, the website uses recaptcha, and its sole job is to stop what you are doing right now, so you'll be facing a lot more trouble.

P.S. I must say though `searchVehicleByRegNo` has some interesting information that is not shown on the webpage, I don't know what you are looking for but I recommend looking at the response.

Comment: the “searchvehiclebyregNo” is the 2nd POST request in my example, how can I add that information to my final request ?

Comment: Just add it in the "payload" for the request to `secure.ami.co.nz/url/css/car/step2/`

Comment: Thanks - how did you find that request URL secure.ami.co.nz/url/css/car/step2/ ..? Did you click submit and inspect the network? Cheers

Comment: struggling with “adding it in the payload” could you perhaps share how you would code it?

Comment: @opticMan yup just submit the form with dummy requests and and look at it in network tab, and 
`response_rego_final = requests.request("POST", "https://secure.ami.co.nz/url/css/car/step2/", headers=headers, data = f"vehicle.redbookVehicleKey={response_rego.json().registrationNo_vehicleList.vehicleCode}&....")` Should do it, ofc Its better to use URLencode

Comment: Awesome thanks @Anunay will try this and see how I get on!

Comment: Have tried a dummy request copying the exact Headers and Form-data as per Network Dev-tools into Postman to visualize the response, but I'm just getting the Step1 page back with no values filled? Any ideas?